# Updating global variables from a function in Lua

Tags: lua, game-engine

Ok this may be a dumb question but Im new to programing so here it gose. I've written a function that I hope to use in a rpg style game to make the player level up based on exp

```
--sets the level based on exp
function levelCheck(exp,level) 
   repeat 
         c=math.sqrt(exp)-(level*4) 
            if ( c>=1 ) then 
               level=level+1 
               print("Congradulations level "..level) 
            end 
   until ( c<1) 
   return level
end
```

Thing is i want this to update the level varible globaly I'm not sure I'm saying that right but please help.

Comment: Why would you want to have this function update that value globally? Presumably, there are dozens of things that need to happen when the level changes, right? Those things should happen in tandem with that change. Also, you may want to ask the question, "If I gave the player X exp, will they gain a level?" To ask that question, you need to call the level-up function, but you *don't* want it to actually cause leveling up. It's best to keep distinct functions *separate*

Answer (score 1):

Global variables in lua are updated from the function whenever you address them by their global name:

```
variable=1
f=function(x) variable=x end
f()
```

Function can alter its argument (actually contents of its argument) if it is a table:

```
f=function(t)
    t.variable=4
end
```

...which answers the title, but not the problem you have. As Nicol Boras commented, you should rethink your ways if your `level` is more than just a number.

Answer (score 0):

It's true level isn't just a number but the plan is to use level as a variable in other equations such as `deff=level*tough+equipment`for example idk that's the plan